# Logo in between navigation bar menu [Wordpress]

Tags: wordpress, navigationbar

I am developing a website by customizing a wordpress theme. I want to display my logo in between navigation bar menu. like this

**Home AboutUs [MY LOGO] Gallery ContactUs**

How can I do this? I can create my own divs to achieve this but don't know what should I write for first 2-3 page's links and other 2-3 page's links

If you have any website in mind displays navigation bar like this and is responsive you can give me its link.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

your are give the background image on class of the div in the menu so ealiy get icon between the menu.
I have a get issue that  type so i have give background image on the class of the div

Comment: hi give some margin and padding for space between navigation bar and logo.